# How To Refer To Continuous Subform Contol

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have an Access 2003 form with one subform, set to continuous forms, in a subform control. For one record in the main form, 1 to many records will appear in the sub form. The data displays properly.

The main form is named **Widgets** and the sub form is named **Transactions**.  There are 5 textbox controls that display the data in the subform.  The one in question is **ReceiptDate**.

What I would like to do is look at the values and determine if there was a receipt for the year 2009, and if so then change the background of that row to yellow so it stands out when the user encounters that condition. Maybe even change the date field's font to boldface..

I tried many ways of referencing the subform's controls.  When I have tried `Me.Transactions.ReceiptDate` I have only received the first record in that subform.  I'd like to be able to loop through them and see if the condition is met.  I tried `Me.Transactions.ReceiptDate(1)` and `Me.Transactions.ReceiptDate(0)` and so forth.

I tried the `For Each ctl In Form.Controls` route as well. It worked for a few iterations and then I received a run-time error 2455 "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report".

I had the subform in "datasheet" mode but thought that was causing me not to be able to read through an array of subform controls.  So I changed it to "continuous" mode.  I get the same errors for either.

Is there a way to reference specific "rows" in the subform and do something based on a value found?  Also, I am performing this in the On Current event as I dont know where else to put the code.  The subform loads before the parent form so its possible that these controls arent even fully "there" but then I do get the first row's date when I try it in the Immediate Window.

**UPDATE 12.23.2010:**

With the gracious help of @Remou I am able to debug.print the ReceiptDate fields from the RecordSet.  This is great because now I can evaluate the data and do certain things based on the values..   The @Remou's code helped me put this into the OnCurrent event:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim frm As Form
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

' Get the form and its recordset.
Set frm = Me.Form
Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

' Move to the first record in the recordset.
rs.MoveFirst

' Move to the first selected record.
rs.Move frm.SelTop - 1

' Enumerate the list of selected records presenting the ReceiptDate field
For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    Debug.Print rs![ReceiptDate]
    rs.MoveNext
Next i
```

So now that I am able to know which row in my subform has a receipt from 2009, I need to be able to highlight the entire row or rows as I come across them in that for loop.  How can I reference the actual row?  Datasheet view or Continuous Forms view - I have tried both.

Conditional Formatting is great but it only allows me to highlight one particular record and I'd much rather be able to do this via VBA because...... from here I will want to give the use the ability to click on any record in the subform and get the receipt details and potentially print them.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you click on a record, that record becomes the current record and you can do what you like with it, including print it (eg on main form `DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", , , "ID=" & Me.MySubformControlName.Form.ID`) Some people also like to put a button on the subform, tgis will appear on each row and make it very clear to the user which record is being printed (`DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", , , "ID=" & Me.ID`). The easiest way to highlight the whole of the current record is with a hidden header field, a little vba and conditional formatting. Let me know if you want details.

Comment: Gotcha on the report printing.  I changed to a continuous forms and planted a cmd button for that.  Works great!

As far as "The easiest way to highlight the whole of the current record is with a hidden header field, a little vba and conditional formatting. Let me know if you want details.", I'd like to see an example of that, sure.  I am trying several things based on your comment above, which arent working for me, so I am definitely a little lost there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, it is best to use conditional formatting.

To refer to a control on a subform, refer to the subform control by name, then the form property to get the form contained, then the control by name:

```
Me.MySubformControlName.Form.MyControl
```

See: http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: I will check that URL out.  I guess that I referenced it correctly in that I get a date back, but its always the first date and there could be 10 subform "rows" to check..  Is there not a control "array" available for iterating through?   Or some other method like that?

Comment: As I mentioned, use conditional formatting. Any reference to a subform control will return rows in the currently selected row, however, conditional formatting will do just what you want.

Comment: You will find Conditional Formatting here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/apply-or-change-conditional-formatting-on-a-control-HP005269166.aspx

Comment: Very well.  That works.  Thank you.  In the case where I would like to retrieve and work with the ReceiptDate's value and maybe the ReceiptNumber on the same row, how would I go about that?  Am I missing something that references an array of controls in that subform?

Comment: If you wish to work with a control or a number of controls in the active row, you can refer to each control or bound field by name, using the syntax above. It is also possible to work with a user defined selection (http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Allow_the_User_to_Select_Multiple_Records_for_Processing) or the recordset or Recordsetclone (Me.MySubformControlName.Form.RecordSet)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got it.  The frm.SelTop = x will set the selected record and from there I can set the background or font style, etc..   Very cool.  A simple test for 2009 and setting the selected record:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim frm As Form
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

' Get the form and its recordset.
Set frm = Me.Form
Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

' Move to the first record in the recordset.
rs.MoveFirst

' Move to the first selected record.
rs.Move 0

' Enumerate the list of selected records presenting
' the CompanyName field in a message box.
For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    If Year(rs![ReceiptDate]) = 2009 Then
        frm.SelTop = i '<-----------------------------
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for me to get the email off the bottom of my continuous form, I used this much simpler code (as I avoided the RecordsetClone code)

```
    Me.[email subform].Form.SelTop = Me.[email subform].Form.Count 'selects the last row
    str = Me.[email subform].Form.Email 'capture the value of the last row
    MsgBox str
```